# Sequencing Elektron Analog Rytm MKII & Elektron Analog Four MKI

Tags: synthesizer

I have this set up:
MIDI OUT of Elektron Analog Rytm MKII -> MIDI IN of Elektron Analog Four MKI

Elektron Analog Four MKI:

```
CLOCK RECEIVE -> ON
CLOCK SEND —> OFF
TRANSPORT RECEIVE -> ON
TRANSPORT SEND -> OFF
PROG. CH RECEIVE -> OFF
PROG CH. SEND -> OFF
```

Elektron Analog Rytm MKII:

```
CLOCK RECEIVE -> OFF
CLOCK SEND —> ON
TRANSPORT RECEIVE -> OFF
TRANSPORT SEND -> OFF
PROG. CH RECEIVE -> OFF
PROG CH. SEND -> OFF
```

It seems that the sync is working fine because when I change the BPM of Elektron Analog Rytm MKII is also changed in the Elektron Analog Four MKI, nevertheless I don't know how to sync both sequencers. 
I push PLAY button of both synthesizers at the same time, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it, more accurate and precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings implies that you'd like to use the rytm as master, and the a4 as slave, no?

Enabling transport send and program change on your rytm should be enough for running transport/clock/pattern duties from the rytm.

Comment: It works but after a while it gets a little but desynchronized :-(

Comment: @Nuñito that's a tricky one. Sync problem can be caused by many different things, and i'm unsure that troubleshooting questions is suitable here. I'd recommend checking elektronauts.com.